# Trying to get property 'ship_date' of non-object

Tags: php

```
$this['order'] = $order = \Spot\Shipment\Models\Order::find($this->param('id'));
```

```
    $progress           = 0;
    $progress_status    = 'warning';
    $shipdate           = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->ship_date);
    $deliverydate       = (($order->deliverytime)? $shipdate->addHours($order->deliverytime->count) :null);
    $today              = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

    $time_diff          = $today->diffInDays($deliverydate, false);

    switch($order->requested){
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put `$order` is most likely null. Work out why, dump the value of `$this->param('id')`, it might be null too.

now, some little tips:

- use a naming convention for your variables, you are mixing snake_case and nocase.
- what is `$this['order']`, some `ArrayAccess` implementation? And why not `$this->order`?
- learn more at phptherightway.com

Also as you are new to StackOverflow, please take some time to write out a more thought out question detailing what is going wrong and provide some context.

Also, think about tags, for example, this question has nothing to do with `mysql` and `phpmyadmin`, correct?

Comment: Yes, of course, I am still learning. If I fell into this problem, please write the correct code ??

Comment: for starters, a `var_dump($this->param('id'))` or `dump(...)` as it seems you are using laravel? the "correct code" is up to you to write, it depends on many factors. Maybe the order you are "finding" has been soft-deleted?